# Is it possible to convert FileReader readAsArrayBuffer data into html5 canvas compatible imageData

Tags: javascript, canvas, filereader

I'm looking for a way to draw an image to a canvas directly from the html5 FileReader api.

The usual method is to create a new image object, wait for onload and then draw it to the canvas with `drawImage()`.

However for a specific case which I do not need to go into I would like to bypass the loading of the image data completely if at all possible.

Since the filereader api supports `readAsArrayBuffer()` I was wondering if there is any way I could take this arraybuffer and convert it into canvas imageData in order to use ctx.putImageData(array) to render the image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the image is a neccessary step I think; at one end of the process you just have a binary blob which could be a JPEG or PNG (or BMP, any other mime type), while at the other you have an array containing raw pixel data. While you could technically code this conversion yourself, the `fileReader.readAsDataURL` and `ctx.drawImage` methods do this for you internally.

FWIW, his is how I draw an image to canvas.

```
// read binary data from file object
var fileRead = function(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = fileReadComplete;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

// convert binary data to image object
var fileReadComplete = function(e){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = e.target.result;
    (function(){
        if (img.complete){
            ctx.drawImage(img);
            }
        else {
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);
            }
        })();
    };
```

Comment: That's pretty much how I do it also. I've played around with using createimagedata and looping through a typedarray but the image comes out garbled.  It's a shame because this would be perfect for this particular application within a webworker.  It would allow being able to send huge images to the worker without having to clone it.  Thanks anyway.  I'll mark the question as answered as soon as I am able.